# Struggling with receiving data through WebSocket API

Tags: python, json, websocket

I'm trying to connect to exchange.blockchain.com server using their API. Here is the [official documentation](https://exchange.blockchain.com/api/#websocket-api) if you want to check it. I'm working on a simple python script to receive Bitcoin prices every `x` seconds. Note: the API has a limit of 1,200 request per minute. Here is the first part of my code:

```
from websocket import create_connection
options = {}
options['origin'] = 'https://exchange.blockchain.com'
url = "wss://ws.prod.blockchain.info/mercury-gateway/v1/ws"
ws = create_connection(url, **options)
msg = '{"token": "{API_SECRET}", "action": "subscribe", "channel": "auth"}'
ws.send(msg)
result =  ws.recv()
print(result)
ws.close()
```

I receive the following output:

```
{ "seqnum":0,
  "event":"subscribed",
  "channel":"auth",
  "readOnly":false }
```

So far everything is correct. Now the official documentation says that I have to suscribe to the channel `prices` to receive market data, so:

```
msg = {
     "action": "subscribe",
     "channel": "prices",
     "symbol": "BTC-USD",
     "granularity": 60
      }

ws.send(str(msg))
result =  ws.recv()
print(result)
ws.close()
```

Output is:

```
{
  "seqnum": 0,
  "event": "subscribed",
  "channel": "prices",
  "symbol": "BTC-USD"
}
```

Everything is fine but, according to the documentation I'm suppose to receive also the following output with the data requested through the channel

```
{
  "seqnum": 2,
  "event": "updated",
  "channel": "prices",
  "symbol": "BTC-USD",
  "price": [1559039640, 8697.24, 8700.98, 8697.27, 8700.98, 0.431]
}
```

Of course, my problem is that I'm not receiving the last and most important part of the output. I think this is because I don't know how an API and socket works. Therefore, I'm missing something in my code. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this API specifically, but it looks to me like you recieve the first response from the api, shown by:

```
{
  "seqnum": 0,
  "event": "subscribed",
  "channel": "prices",
  "symbol": "BTC-USD"
}
```

And then you exit before receiving the updates.

You need to keep the connection open to continue receiving the updates. Perhaps you can try something like:

```
import websockets as ws
import asyncio
async def givme_bitcoins(websocket): # takes in the ws connection object
    while True:
        try:
            data = await websocket.recv()
        except ws.ConnectionClosed:
            print(f"Terminated")
            break

        print(data)



async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait([givme_bitcoins(URL)])
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

To explain the previous snippet, the general idea is that we open an asynchronous connection through websockets, and we continue to send/receive data with the API.For this code to work, you still need to do the saem process in your code, as in: authenticated, subscribe to channels...etc.).

Comment: Thanks you! You inspired me to make it through my own way, just like that: `while True: result = ws.recv() print(result)`

Comment: @DennisConcepciónMartín Happy to help : ) Although your implementation for while True will work fine for printing results, when dealing with websockets I recommend that you use asynchronous functions so that you don't block the execution of your code. Keep in mind that after receiving data you will potentially want to also send data or process data outside of that True loop. Additionally, the while True will work for printing data but will only limit to one action/endpoint at a time, and you can't scale that to fetch data from other end points for example.

Comment: That's right, I just realized it when I run my while True code... I will try to implement your code.

Comment: @DennisConcepciónMartín Sure. Let me know if you need further help.